# Creating a new table in sonar database

Tags: plugins, sonarqube

I have to create a new table in sonar database to develop my plugin.
Is it possible to create a new table in sonar database using java.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should not try to extend Sonar DB when developing a plugin, otherwise this will cost you a lot when doing the successive migrations to future versions of Sonar.

Instead, you should use Sonar API to achieve what you want. And if you miss some features, then you can come and discuss it on Sonar DEV mailing-list.

But I advise you not to try to do some fancy stuff with the DB, that will cost you a lot of effort to maintain in the future.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. is sonar stores all the folder names and file names in a project to the database?

Comment: I analyzed a java project and in "Projects" table it only stores the names of folders and filed located in src/main/java directory. the names of resource files and folders are not storing in database